# What is the best practice to chain realm queries in Android?

Tags: android, realm

So, I have an Android app that uses realm.io. I have to run queries asynchronously like this :

```
public static void getProductsByCategoryId(Realm realm, 
     String categoryId,
     OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Product>> callback) {

    RealmResults<Product> result = realm.where(Product.class)
            .equalTo(CATEGORY, categoryId)
            .findAllAsync();
    result.addChangeListener(callback);
}
```

The callback will process this response, but then I need to run another query in sequence. So, you'll have queryA => process response => queryB => process response. So, the callback may have code like this

```
.....
getProductsByCategoryId(app.getRealmInstance(), "ABC123", firstCallback);
.....
private OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Product>> firstCallback = new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Product>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Product> realmProducts, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {

                mProdList.addAll(mRealm.copyFromRealm(realmProducts));

                // get more product info (2nd call)
                MainApplication.getMoreProductInfo(mRealm, mCatId, false, secondCallback);
        }
    };
```

Currently, my understanding is that you would run queryB in the callback of queryA ? Looking at the requirements for the app, I will end up with chains of 3 or 4 queries. Is this an appropriate approach, or is there a specific pattern I should be using ? I haven't found any guidance yet in the Realm documentation.

Comment: `Is this an appropriate approach` no, there are about 3 things wrong with this approach. Although there's most likely a badly designed schema in the background if it takes you 4 queries to get all your data.

Comment: Well, it's not really possible to guess *why you need 4 consequent queries in the first place*. Generally for optimal use, the RealmResults that you **aren't supposed to copy from the Realm** should be derived from a single query, which would obtain the objects that do contain every information you need, in the right order (sorted). Depending on whether it is possible *without* using 4 queries is a question of its own, AND on top of that as you copy from the Realm, this could just be 4 synchronous queries on the same BG thread. That way your RealmResults wouldn't be killed by GC *sometimes*.

Comment: In ye olde days of SQL databases you would have inner or outer joins that would overcome unusual queries that were not conceived in the original DB design or you didn't have the permissions to create views. This scenario still occurs today. One method I have used to overcome such a situation is to chain queries. I'm looking for a better way. If you don't know how to solve it, then it doesn't necessarily mean it's not a legitimate question. Perhaps it's beyond your level of skill, in such a case leave it for someone else. You've suggested an answer, but I can't mark it if it's a comment

Comment: There is just not enough information here to have a vision of the whole problem. If it is *impossible* to make the answer be part of the schema with a single query, then you'll have to ditch lazy-loading and execute the queries synchronously on a background thread with a `try-with-resources` for the local Realm. Then copy the final results from the Realm. Maybe that's what you're interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally an indication of bad schema design if you need to do multiple queries in order to retrieve your result set, because the way Realm works is that if you can define your query results with *one* query (and you don't use `realm.copyFromRealm()` which you generally don't need to use anyways), then its elements and the results itself are all lazy-loaded.

If you cannot accomplish that, then even then, generally you probably shouldn't chain `find*Async` calls, because **any** RealmResults that you don't store as a field variable has a chance of being consumed by GC, and its change listener won't be called when `isLoaded()` is true (because said RealmResults no longer exists).

So what you really seem to want to do is just execute multiple queries on a background thread then return copied results to the main thread, in which case it'd just look like this

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool(); // or some other pool
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public void getQueryResults(DataLoadedCallback callback) {
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            realm.refresh(); // <-- might not be necessary
            RealmResults<XYZ> results1 = realm.where(XYZ.class)./*...*/.findAll();
            RealmResults<ZXY> results2 = realm.where(ZXY.class)./*...*/.findAll();
            RealmResults<YZX> results3 = realm.where(YZX.class)./*...*/.findAll();
            List<Something> someList = new LinkedList<>(); 
            for/*do magic transform things*/
                someList.add(blah /* blah is not a managed RealmObject */);
            }
            handler.post(() -> {
                callback.onDataLoaded(Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(someList)));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, the schema design is not in the best shape, but I'm working on a large project that is not agile enough to optimise the schema. So, I'm forced to take this unusual step in running multiple queries. Thanks for the alternative approach.. am trying this out.. BTW would there be an issue to use a standard AsyncTask in place of the handler, and process it using "doInBackground" and surface the results in onPostExecute ?

Comment: I have a general distrust for AsyncTask, but theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining queries in the callbacks are fine and "should just work", but it would be far more efficient if you can express what you want is as few queries as possible.

Ideally, we should have a query language that is powerful enough to express everything you want in one query. We are not fully there yet, but we would be very interested to hear more about what specific requirements you have.

Also, it isn't clear why you are using `copyFromRealm` in the method you posted, but in an ideal situation that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: AFAIK the asynchronous query he adds the change listener to can be consumed by GC and his chain will stop, considering each will execute "sometime later" and it'll only be valid if each change listener has also been called after `isLoaded()` is true, no?

Comment: It depends on how the secondary listeners are stored, I cannot tell from the code what `MainApplication.getMoreProductInfo` does. But yes, it is relatively easy to risk them getting GC'ed if you chain them.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior thanks for reaching out. copyFromRealm is simply used to convert the results into an ArrayList, as that content is used in other ways in the app. It seemed like a useful utility method to convert results. But it shouldn't distract from the premise of my question as to how one would reliably execute chained queries with Realm in Android. Background : This is a catalogue app from a complicated data model, to build a product page whose content is buried across multiple tables. Please make ur own assumptions to propose ur preferred approach. Apologies if thats a bit too broad.